# How to plot the position of occurrence in python data frame

Tags: python, pandas, plot

For example I have a data frame like the following:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  0
3  1  0  1
4  1  0  1
5  1  0  0
6  0  1  0
7  0  1  1
8  0  1  0
9  0  1  1
```

How can I plot a graph like the following that indicates the index position of column `A`, `B`, and `C` that had a 1?
[image: plot of the index position]

The top bar shows column `A`, the middle bar shows column `B`, and the bottom bar shows column `C`. The x-axis are the index. For each bar, blue means that there is a 1 at this index for this column, and grey means the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data in `df`, you can call `plt.imshow` on the transposed dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(df.T, cmap='Blues')
```

[image]

edit: For datasets with rows >> columns or columns >> rows the scaling can be messed up. This can be changed by changing the `aspect` of the figure. I am using 10 here, but you should probably play around with some values (maybe 0.1 to 100)

```
plt.imshow(df.T, cmap='Blues')
plt.gca().set_aspect(10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason when I tired this function it is only giving me an empty axis...

Comment: @KaihuaHou This likely means that you have many more rows than columns in your original data. To adjust display, change the aspect of the figure (see edits).

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work with this. However, I have more than 900 rows, and the figure looks really blurry and un clear. Is there a way to generate a clear figure like the one I showed in the question?

Comment: @KaihuaHou default imshow uses interpolation. Switch it off by doing: plt.imshow(df.T, cmap="Blues", interpolation='none')